# Which is correct - molybdate or molybdenate?

Tags: nomenclature

Most websites (including Wikipedia) say that the anion MoO<sub>4</sub><sup>2-</sup> is called a molybdate ion, although some websites use molybdenate instead. Which one is correct, and if one of them is correct, is the other term still allowed?

Comment: Where did you find the term - molybdenate?

Comment: @OscarLanzi Molybdus is just the ancient greek for "lead" (see e.g. https://www.rsc.org/periodic-table/element/42/molybdenum , https://www.britannica.com/science/molybdenum ) - I'm not aware of any mythological aspect to this

Comment: Yes, and a Google search of "Molybdus" yields no results relating to a mythological character.

Comment: [You may find my comment on this interesting. Yes, there is no mythological aspect to it](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/151872/are-the-names-for-chemical-elements-the-same-in-both-modern-greek-and-classical#comment309907_151872). (cc @IanBush)

Comment: I have just checked Wikipedia. Note that the ion is called the molybdate ion, and the term "molybdenate" is just a redirect to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do a Google ngram of the terms 'molybdate' and 'molybdenate', you will find 'molybdate' standing out.

[image]

No one known why the 'en' was kept when you can simply shorten it to molybd-*ate* instead of molybden-*ate* (like phosph-ate and not phosphor-ate). However, the latter didn't got totally eliminated. Some research papers([here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/292583045_Inhibitive_effects_of_molybdenate_on_iron_artifacts_during_desalination_process) is a recent example) and textbooks still uses 'molybdenate'. The following image is from a physics textbook published in 2020.

[image]

Comment: Same thing with tungstate vs tungstenate: https://imgur.com/75IPtBq

Comment: I assume that for many non-native speakers (and possibly some natives too), the short right forms may not feel right by their guts and if they do not know they are actually right, they may use the longer form. E.g. I have learnt English - aside of very basics - after my formal education, therefore I had later often struggles with technical or scientific terminology.

Answer (score 9):

According to Table X of the Red Book (‘Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry – IUPAC recommendations 2005’), the anion name for molybdenum is **molybdate.**

Comment: Does the Table X of the Red Book say if molybdenate is allowed?

Comment: @Praseodymium-141 "molybdenate" is not mentioned in the Red Book.

Comment: I guess molybdenate may be in respective forms present in non EN language variants, that may occasionally by a sneaky way backport to English, if a chemist is unsure.  E.g., in Czech, "sodium molybdate" is "molybdenan sodný".